# WPF Viewport3d scale in layout

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a simple Layout of a WPF Window which is structured like a StackPanel. A menu at the top and a big area for a viewport3d underneath where I am showing 3d graphic objects. 
How can I set the viewport3d Element to take the full free amount of space below the menu?

I tried basic setup like this ...

```
<StackPanel>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="File"></MenuItem>
    </Menu>
        <Viewport3D>
            ... some 3d content here
        </Viewport3D>
</StackPanel>
```

... but that makes the viewport height zero (the width already seems to adapt to full width of the window). Entering a specific height does not make sense, and `Height="Auto"` does not make the viewport take the remaining height. Maybe StackPanel is not the right choice here?

I want the window to be resizable.

Comment: ViewBox is your friend you can try ViewBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a grid with 2 rows. First row's height is set to Auto. Second row's height is set to *.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu Grid.Row="0">
        <MenuItem Header="File"></MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <Viewport3D Grid.Row="1">
        ... some 3d content here
    </Viewport3D>
</Grid>
```

Here's a complete example (scene is from a MS example):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu Grid.Row="0">
            <MenuItem Header="File"></MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <Viewport3D Grid.Row="1">
            <!-- Add a camera. -->
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera 
                    FarPlaneDistance="20" 
                    LookDirection="0,0,1" 
                    UpDirection="0,1,0" 
                    NearPlaneDistance="1" 
                    Position="0,0,-3" 
                    FieldOfView="45" />
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <!-- Add models. -->
            <Viewport3D.Children>
                <ModelVisual3D>
                    <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                        <Model3DGroup >
                            <Model3DGroup.Children>
                                <!-- Lights, MeshGeometry3D and DiffuseMaterial objects are added to the ModelVisual3D. -->
                                <DirectionalLight Color="#FFFFFFFF" Direction="3,-4,5" />
                                <!-- Define a red cone. -->
                                <GeometryModel3D>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D 
Positions="0.293893 -0.5 0.404509  0.475528 -0.5 0.154509  0 0.5 0  0.475528 -0.5 0.154509  0 0.5 0  0 0.5 0  0.475528 -0.5 0.154509  0.475528 -0.5 -0.154509  0 0.5 0  0.475528 -0.5 -0.154509  0 0.5 0  0 0.5 0  0.475528 -0.5 -0.154509  0.293893 -0.5 -0.404509  0 0.5 0  0.293893 -0.5 -0.404509  0 0.5 0  0 0.5 0  0.293893 -0.5 -0.404509  0 -0.5 -0.5  0 0.5 0  0 -0.5 -0.5  0 0.5 0  0 0.5 0  0 -0.5 -0.5  -0.293893 -0.5 -0.404509  0 0.5 0  -0.293893 -0.5 -0.404509  0 0.5 0  0 0.5 0  -0.293893 -0.5 -0.404509  -0.475528 -0.5 -0.154509  0 0.5 0  -0.475528 -0.5 -0.154509  0 0.5 0  0 0.5 0  -0.475528 -0.5 -0.154509  -0.475528 -0.5 0.154509  0 0.5 0  -0.475528 -0.5 0.154509  0 0.5 0  0 0.5 0  -0.475528 -0.5 0.154509  -0.293892 -0.5 0.404509  0 0.5 0  -0.293892 -0.5 0.404509  0 0.5 0  0 0.5 0  -0.293892 -0.5 0.404509  0 -0.5 0.5  0 0.5 0  0 -0.5 0.5  0 0.5 0  0 0.5 0  0 -0.5 0.5  0.293893 -0.5 0.404509  0 0.5 0  0.293893 -0.5 0.404509  0 0.5 0  0 0.5 0  " 
Normals="0.7236065,0.4472139,0.5257313  0.2763934,0.4472138,0.8506507  0.5308242,0.4294462,0.7306172  0.2763934,0.4472138,0.8506507  0,0.4294458,0.9030925  0.5308242,0.4294462,0.7306172  0.2763934,0.4472138,0.8506507  -0.2763934,0.4472138,0.8506507  0,0.4294458,0.9030925  -0.2763934,0.4472138,0.8506507  -0.5308242,0.4294462,0.7306172  0,0.4294458,0.9030925  -0.2763934,0.4472138,0.8506507  -0.7236065,0.4472139,0.5257313  -0.5308242,0.4294462,0.7306172  -0.7236065,0.4472139,0.5257313  -0.858892,0.429446,0.279071  -0.5308242,0.4294462,0.7306172  -0.7236065,0.4472139,0.5257313  -0.8944269,0.4472139,0  -0.858892,0.429446,0.279071  -0.8944269,0.4472139,0  -0.858892,0.429446,-0.279071  -0.858892,0.429446,0.279071  -0.8944269,0.4472139,0  -0.7236065,0.4472139,-0.5257313  -0.858892,0.429446,-0.279071  -0.7236065,0.4472139,-0.5257313  -0.5308242,0.4294462,-0.7306172  -0.858892,0.429446,-0.279071  -0.7236065,0.4472139,-0.5257313  -0.2763934,0.4472138,-0.8506507  -0.5308242,0.4294462,-0.7306172  -0.2763934,0.4472138,-0.8506507  0,0.4294458,-0.9030925  -0.5308242,0.4294462,-0.7306172  -0.2763934,0.4472138,-0.8506507  0.2763934,0.4472138,-0.8506507  0,0.4294458,-0.9030925  0.2763934,0.4472138,-0.8506507  0.5308249,0.4294459,-0.7306169  0,0.4294458,-0.9030925  0.2763934,0.4472138,-0.8506507  0.7236068,0.4472141,-0.5257306  0.5308249,0.4294459,-0.7306169  0.7236068,0.4472141,-0.5257306  0.8588922,0.4294461,-0.27907  0.5308249,0.4294459,-0.7306169  0.7236068,0.4472141,-0.5257306  0.8944269,0.4472139,0  0.8588922,0.4294461,-0.27907  0.8944269,0.4472139,0  0.858892,0.429446,0.279071  0.8588922,0.4294461,-0.27907  0.8944269,0.4472139,0  0.7236065,0.4472139,0.5257313  0.858892,0.429446,0.279071  0.7236065,0.4472139,0.5257313  0.5308242,0.4294462,0.7306172  0.858892,0.429446,0.279071  "                   TriangleIndices="0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 " />
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                <SolidColorBrush  Color="Red" Opacity="1.0"/>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                </GeometryModel3D>
                            </Model3DGroup.Children>
                        </Model3DGroup>
                    </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                </ModelVisual3D>
            </Viewport3D.Children>
        </Viewport3D>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```